How to change the background colour of the section up/down arrow
The corporate colour scheme dictates that the section should have a dark blue colour. The implication of this is that the expand/collapse icon (up/down arrow) is barely visible (see image below)
I know we can change the section label background colour with something like this:
.orbeon .xbl-fr-section h2.fr-section-title .fr-section-label.fr-section-open {background-color: #58b6d2;}

How can we change only the background colour of the icon?


Try the following CSS, which removes the background images and replaces them with Font Awesome carets. In this example, the carets are set to appear in black, but you can change their color to make them more visible on your dark blue background—white, matching the text color, might work well.

/* Common styles for both open and closed sections */
.fr-section-open::before,
.fr-section-closed::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

/* Specific content for open section (downward caret) */
.fr-section-open::before {
  content: "\f0d7"; /* Unicode for 'caret-down' icon */
}

/* Specific content for closed section (rightward caret) */
.fr-section-closed::before {
  content: "\f0da"; /* Unicode for 'caret-right' icon */
}

/* Ensure no background images are applied */
.fr-section-open,
.fr-section-closed {
  background-image: none !important;
}


Thanks Alex,
I had to add "color: white;" statement to change the color of the icon.
FYI - it doesnt work in our system - it looks like there might be a Awesome Fonts issue..

@PeteAtkin Are you saying that color: white doesn't work in your system, or that the entire caret fails to appear as shown in the animation above?

It appears that the "font awesome" doesnt work using STYLE, it does however work if you enter a font id in the Custom CSS Classes field within a control.
I will report the issue to SAP  tomorrow.

@PeteAtkin Are you referring to adding a custom CSS class to the section? If so, are you saying that the CSS provided above doesn’t work as it is, but it does work if you add a custom CSS class to the section and modify the CSS to target that class?
